# Why I am getting different intervals, when my scrape interval in Prometheus is 15s?

Tags: prometheus, opentsdb

I have my prometheus with scrape interval of 15s, but why my values below are not in the incitements of 15?

- 62476 @1592659176.118
- 62496 @1592659186.118
- 62524 @1592659206.118
- 62532 @1592659216.118
- 62552 @1592659236.118
- 62564 @1592659246.118
- 62576 @1592659266.117
- 62584 @1592659276.118
- 62596 @1592659296.118
- 62608 @1592659306.118
- 62636 @1592659326.118
- 62644 @1592659336.117
  Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Maybe this interesting could help you https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/PrometheusScrapeIntervalBit

Comment: That looks like 2 different targets being scraped with a 30s interval each. I'd double check that your configuration says what you think it says.